# Starting with MeanJS. Not found module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, meanjs

I'm getting MeanJS.
Setting up project follow [this](https://github.com/meanjs/mean).
`npm install` works fine. But when `grunt`, i got this error.

```js
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'di'
Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'simple-fmt'
Loading "nodemon.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
Loading "protractor_coverage.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'dargs-object'
Loading "protractor_coverage.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'dargs-object'

Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Running "less:dist" (less) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 110 files lint free.

Running "eslint:target" (eslint) task

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'parserlib' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Did i miss something?

Comment: This error related with your grunt dependencies, use ``npm install packageName --save`` for each missing module, or this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing for install all of them.

Comment: Are you sure the `npm install` command worked fine? Can you repeat it?

Comment: @styopdev thank for suggesting. i tried npm-install-missing.
i got  `npm-install-missing: No modules seem to be missing.  Huzzah!` but no help.
@Michelem  `npm install` had no error log. i also tried it many time but no change

Comment: @DươngMinhKhoa so you should install them manually..

Comment: Before reisntalling node modules with `npm install` try `npm cache clean`